# Getting error unable to determine composite primary key while creating strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I am working on ASP.NET-MVC application, I am trying to create strongly typed view from controller but I am getting following Error as show in diagram

[image]

[image]

### Model class

```
public class PropertyRentingApplication
{
     public PropertyRentingApplication() { }


     [Key]
     [Display(Name = "Application ID")]
     public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

     [Key, ForeignKey("PropertyType")]
     [Display(Name = "Property Type ID")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Property Type ID")]
     public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }

     [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
     [Display(Name = "Student ID")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Student ID")]
     public int StudentID { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Application Reference")]
     [MaxLength(150)]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Application Reference")]
     public string ApplicationReference { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Date Of Application")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Date of Application Been Submitted")]
     public System.DateTime DateOfApplication { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Secure Entire Property")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Information on If You Want to Secure Entire Property")]
     public bool SecureEntireProperty { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Application Status")]
     [MaxLength(50)]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Application Status")]
     public string ApplicationStatus { get; set; }

     public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
     public Student Student { get; set; }

}
```

I have updated as below " [Column(Order = 1)]" but is still throughing same error

```
[Key]
     [Display(Name = "Application ID")]
     [Column(Order = 0)]
     public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

     [Key, ForeignKey("PropertyType")]
     [Display(Name = "Property Type ID")]
     [Column(Order = 2)]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Property Type ID")]
     public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }

     [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
     [Display(Name = "Student ID")]
     [Column(Order = 1)]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Student ID")]
     public int StudentID { get; set; }
```

Comment: You need to decorate your key columns with `[Column(Order = 0)]` and so forth, to *define* what order these columns appear in in the key

Comment: dunno if it matters or not, but in your code snipped `StudentID` is marked as a Key, but not in your screenshot of your columns.

Comment: @marc_s: Please post that as answer, since it is the answer. Otherwise, the OP can't accept it and this question will perpetually remain "Unanswered".

Comment: please review my question at bottom, I have add  [Column(Order = 0)] but still getting error!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate your key columns with `[Column(Order = 0)]`, `[Column(Order = 1)]` and so forth, to define what order these columns appear in in the key